# How to write junit for guice injected static variable which is declared inside Enum

Tags: java, junit, guice, powermockito

I have enum like this

```
public enum NumbersJk {

    ONE {
        public void processCommand(Info Info) {
            log.info("what is in process " + process)
            process.add(Info);
        }
    },
    TWO {
        public void processCommand(Info Info) {
            process.subtract(Info);
        }
    },
    TEN {
        public void processCommand(Info Info) {
            process.divide(Info);
        }
    }

    @Inject
    private static ProcessNumber process;

    public abstract void processCommand(Info Info) throws Exception;
}
```

It was injected using guice like this     `requestStaticInjection(NumbersJk.class);`

```
public class AddNumbers {
   public string testMethod(bla,bla,commandToExecute){
      Info info = convert(bla,bla)
      NumbersJk.valueOf(commandToExecute).processCommand(Info);
   }
}
```

Now I am trying to write junit (powermockito) for this

Junit

```
@Mock
private ProcessNumber process = new ProcessNumber(new depsencey(), dependecny2());

@InjectMocks
AddNumber addNumber;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}


@Test
@SneakyThrows
public void test() { 
    addNumber.testMethod(1,2,ONE) 
}
```

This internally calls

```
NumbersJk.valueOf(commandToExecute).processCommand(Info);
```

And getting exception `java.lang.NullPointerException: null`

This is `ProcessNumber` is coming as `null`

```
log.info("what is in process " + process) printed as `what is in process null`
```

Question:

How to inject the class `ProcessNumber` in junit

Thanks
Jk

Comment: I think `String result = NumbersJk.valueOf(commandToExecute).processCommand(Info);` cannot be compiled, because of `processCommand(Info)` returns `void`.

Comment: hi i edited the question. This is sample code so by mistake i added. The problem is how to inject ProcessNumber inside enum so that i can test in junit

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
We can use powermock to solve this problem `Whitebox.setInternalState(NumbersJk.class, process);`

Code:

```
@Mock
private ProcessNumber process = new ProcessNumber(new depsencey(), dependecny2());

@InjectMocks
AddNumber addNumber;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    Whitebox.setInternalState(NumbersJk.class, process);
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}


@Test
@SneakyThrows
public void test() { 
    addNumber.testMethod(1,2,ONE) 
}
```